# How to unpack bits from packbits results?

Tags: python, numpy, bit-manipulation

I am not familial with np.packbits and I want to perform a huge XOR operation by using it.

Here is my toy example:

```
import numpy as np

# Example arrays
u_values = np.array([[True, True, True, True, True, True, False, True, True, True],
                     [True, True, True, True, True, True, True, False, False, True],
                     [True, True, True, True, False, True, False, True, True, True],
                     [True, True, True, True, False, True, True, False, False, True],
                     [True, True, True, True, True, False, False, False, False, True],
                     [True, True, True, False, False, False, False, False, False, True],
                     [True, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, True],
                     [True, True, False, True, False, True, False, True, True, True]])

v_values = np.array([[True, True, True, True, True, True, False, True, True, True],
                     [True, False, True, False, True, True, True, False, False, True],
                     [True, True, True, True, False, True, False, True, True, True],
                     [True, False, True, True, False, False, True, False, False, True],
                     [True, True, False, True, True, False, False, False, False, True],
                     [True, True, True, False, False, True, False, False, False, True]])
```

I tried to use the following codes as below:

```
u_values_packed = np.packbits(u_values, axis=1)
v_values_packed = np.packbits(v_values, axis=1)
result_packed = u_values_packed[:, None, :] ^ v_values_packed[None, :, :]

result_packed = result_packed.reshape((-1, result_packed.shape[2]))
result_unpacked = np.unpackbits(result_packed, axis=1)
print(result_unpacked.shape) #(48,16)
```

I got the output shape (48,16) instead of (48,10).

How can I get the desired result so that I can perform XOR for each line of u_values with v_values resulting in a total dimension of (48,10)?

Here is the entired example output:

```
[[False False False False False False False False False False]
 [False  True False  True False False  True  True  True False]
 [False False False False  True False False False False False]
 [False  True False False  True  True  True  True  True False]
 [False False  True False False  True False  True  True False]
 [False False False  True  True False False  True  True False]
 [False False False False False False  True  True  True False]
 [False  True False  True False False False False False False]
 [False False False False  True False  True  True  True False]
 [False  True False False  True  True False False False False]
 [False False  True False False  True  True False False False]
 [False False False  True  True False  True False False False]
 [False False False False  True False False False False False]
 [False  True False  True  True False  True  True  True False]
 [False False False False False False False False False False]
 [False  True False False False  True  True  True  True False]
 [False False  True False  True  True False  True  True False]
 [False False False  True False False False  True  True False]
 [False False False False  True False  True  True  True False]
 [False  True False  True  True False False False False False]
 [False False False False False False  True  True  True False]
 [False  True False False False  True False False False False]
 [False False  True False  True  True  True False False False]
 [False False False  True False False  True False False False]
 [False False False False False  True False  True  True False]
 [False  True False  True False  True  True False False False]
 [False False False False  True  True False  True  True False]
 [False  True False False  True False  True False False False]
 [False False  True False False False False False False False]
 [False False False  True  True  True False False False False]
 [False False False  True  True  True False  True  True False]
 [False  True False False  True  True  True False False False]
 [False False False  True False  True False  True  True False]
 [False  True False  True False False  True False False False]
 [False False  True  True  True False False False False False]
 [False False False False False  True False False False False]
 [False  True  True  True  True  True False  True  True False]
 [False False  True False  True  True  True False False False]
 [False  True  True  True False  True False  True  True False]
 [False False  True  True False False  True False False False]
 [False  True False  True  True False False False False False]
 [False  True  True False False  True False False False False]
 [False False  True False  True False False False False False]
 [False  True  True  True  True False  True  True  True False]
 [False False  True False False False False False False False]
 [False  True  True False False  True  True  True  True False]
 [False False False False  True  True False  True  True False]
 [False False  True  True False False False  True  True False]]
```

Comment: can you provide the exact expected output for clarity?

Comment: @mozway updated the question by providing the desired output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`numpy.packbits` pads to a multiple of 8bits with 0, as [documented](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.packbits.html). When doing unpack, there is no way for numpy to know what you aren't interested in these extra bits. You have to throw them away by hand:

`result_unpacked = np.unpackbits(result_packed, axis=1)[:, :10]`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Actually if the dimension of my array is not fix (10 in this case) so I need to use u_values.shape[1] instead of 10 right?

Comment: @Erwin Yep, I just used the concrete example you provided.

Comment: Ok i see, thanks. Voted up and accepted the answer.